# Rest API alternative to polling for asynchronous long running tasks

Tags: rest, flask, flask-restful

I have created a flask restplus API that accepts xlsx file as input and returns an XML. This would be consumed internally by our different APIs

The current flow:

- Users POST an xlsx file by calling /upload endpoint.
- API accepts the file, stores it and returns a file id.
- User sends another request to /run by providing the file id for
  processing
- API puts the request in rabbitMQ queue and returns 202 with a
  location URL To poll for the status.
- celery worker picks up the request and start processing it. It takes
  a while to complete.
- Meanwhile user can poll for the status
- Once completed, API sends 303, with an another location URL to
  download the file.
- User hits the new URL to download the file.

However, our architect team is not in the favor of giving polling mechanism for the client and asking us to take another approach, may be a callback URL.
They have a say in it - "busy wait with sleep to check whether task is completed, is not a good programming practice."

I would like to know  is there any different approach client can take without having a polling for the status. Callback is the one i am aware  of but it's not in place yet.

Comment: "Architect team." Haha. In my opinion, it's on them to explain their assertion about this being bad practice and justify the extra work; I know it's rarely the case, but if there's a manager or some other third party that could arbitrate this for you, I'd try to put it back on them. If they don't like the way it's being done now, it ought to be their responsibility to propose a solution and get the ball rolling.

Comment: Also, just as a note: You may want to consider revisiting how you're defining your endpoints; [REST is pretty specific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Relationship_between_URI_and_HTTP_methods) regarding how that's typically done. I'm not saying this is the be-all, end-all of API architecture, but if you call your API RESTful, people are likely to make reasonable assumptions about it that aren't going to pan out the way you've described your endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Using a callback URL makes at least one potentially significant requirement: The client must be directly accessible over a shared network at a static location. That's not necessarily a problem if all possible clients can be assumed to both satisfy this requirement *and* accept connections from the API, but that information is certainly vital, and adding this requirement could cause serious headaches down the road if at some point people want to hit this API from, for example, desktop applications.

Since the stated reason for rejecting your workflow is "good programming practice," you're starting from a disadvantage regarding coming up with something that will be accepted without further information. If the callback URL accessibility requirement is something they're willing to live with, that's certainly an option, but I'd say you'd need to account for and alert users regarding failure states pretty carefully.

Another possibility would be a separate all-in-one endpoint that either calls the others itself and blocks or just directly executes the internals without the intermediate requests (though this would probably require either doing your own polling, bypassing the queue, or using your *own* internal callbacks to finish the request when file processing is done).

I'd also revisit whatever requirements were provided and identify how and why they were either incorrect or insufficient to adequately define an acceptable deliverable (or whether there was a misinterpretation on your end). This seems unlikely to be a one-time issue, and if there's a process fix or something like internal development guidelines that can potentially limit future misunderstandings or architecture disagreements, that'd be worth working on.